# Schengen business visa - multiple entry

Tags: visas, schengen, business-travel

I need to travel to Italy on official tour but is unable get an appointment at the Italian embassy in India or their consulates. However understand that getting appointment is faster in Swiss embassy.

Can I go in for a Schengen business visa through the Swiss embassy and travel directly to Italy? Otherwise I plan to enter Switzerland, stay for a day and then travel to Italy.

Comment: You will have to convince the Swiss embassy that the prime goal of your trip is Switzerland.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/can-i-go-to-germany-with-a-schengen-visa-from-another-country-after-failing-to-g

Answer (score 2):

If you tell the truth in your application, the Swiss embassy will send you to the Italian embassy.

If you lie in your application, you risk that your itinerary looks incoherent and gets denied for that reason, or that your entry is denied when the lie is detected.

The *only* way how such a scheme would work if Switzerland gave you a multiple-entry visa with long validity and duration, and if you went to Switzerland first and to Italy next, on a second, separate trip. But multiple-entry visa are usually only given after a long history of single-entry visa.